# Java int array not keeping contents

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I am writing a multithreaded application that is meant to emulate a simple z80 machine, and I'm having trouble with the display portion. I have a Screen class that extends a JPanel, and a DSP class to handle all video processing on a separate thread.

After using `println()` to investigate, I have determined the issue is copying the result data from the DSP class to a frame buffer in the Screen class. When the DSP writes to the display, the array keeps the data until it comes time to paint the component, where the entire array gets erased and the screen remains black. Below is my code for the Screen class, because I know the DSP class is functioning the way it should. The commented print lines are in reference to the DSP writing all white pixels to the frame buffer.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

/**
 *
 * @author James
 */
public class Screen extends JPanel{
    private int[] memory = new int[153600];
    private int location = 0;
    private boolean writing;
    private BufferedImage img;
    private Timer timer;

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        int index = 0;
        for(int x = 319; x > 0; x--){
            for(int y = 1; y < 240; y ++){
                System.out.println(memory[index + 1]); // always prints zero
                int color = (memory[index] + (memory[index + 1] * 256));
                img.setRGB(x, y, convert16_32(color));
                index += 2;
            }
        }
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
    }

    public void writeData(int d){//called from a seperate thread
        if(writing){
            memory[location] = d;
            location ++;
            if(location == 153600){
                location = 0;
                for (int n : memory) { //debug check to make sure the memory was properly written to
                    System.out.println(memory[n]);//prints 255 like it should
                }
                writing = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public void writeCommand(){
        writing = true;
    }

    public Screen() {
        img = new BufferedImage(320, 240, BufferedImage.TYPE_USHORT_565_RGB);
        timer = new Timer(1000/30, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (!writing) { //ensures screen is not updated when writing to memory
                    action();
                }
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }

    private void action(){
        this.repaint();
    }

    private int convert16_32(int rgb) { // conerts 16 bit color to 32 bit color
        int r = ((rgb & 0xF800) << 16);
        int g = ((rgb & 0x07E0) << 11);
        int b = ((rgb & 0x001F) << 5);
        return (r | g | b);
    }
}
```

I have tried surrounding the write code into a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` method, but that just caused major lag and didn't solve the issue. Can someone help me find what I'm doing wring, because I am out of ideas.

Comment: `synchronised`? Or `AtomicBoolean`?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most likely that you are not properly synchronizing memory access between the threads.  As a result, the DSP thread most likely writes its data to its processor cache, but the data is discarded instead of getting flushed to main memory for other threads to see.

You need to synchronize access to the `memory` array in some way.  The simplest way to do this would be to make the `paintComponent` and `writeData` methods both `synchronized`.  Depending on how your specific application behaves, that might cause more contention than you would prefer, so you might need to some up with a more sophisticated approach, but some method of synchronization is needed when you want data written in one thread to become visible in other threads.

Comment: Okay, I've never used synchronised before, so I'll have to learn that. I'll let you know of my results.